# C# show 6 decimals returns wrong value

Tags: c#

C# Console application. I have the following code:

```
next = 758550
next = (double)next / Math.Pow(10, 6);
file.WriteLine(next);
```

Instead of returning 0.758550 it returns 0.75855 (without the zero at the end) even though I specified it to be double.

Comment: "even though I specified it to be double" => Where did you read that `double` gets printed with a specific number of decimal digits?

Comment: What's the `file` variable? double is just a storage format in .NET. The way this variable is printed is something entirely different.

Comment: Why do you think making it a double will add a trailing zero?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, `double` doesn't preserve trailing zeroes. It's meant to be a type which is about the magnitude of values, not the precise decimal digits.

However, `decimal` *does* retain trailing zeroes, so if you write:

```
decimal next = 758550m;
next = next * 0.000001m;
file.WriteLine(next);
```

... that will show you what you want. Interestingly, dividing by 1000000 *doesn't* work here. I suspect the algorithm is *something* along the lines of "retain as many insignificant decimal digits as are in either operand", but it's not entirely clear.

Alternatively, you can specify a custom format for your `double` value instead:

```
file.WriteLine(next.ToString("0.000000"));
```

or:

```
file.WriteLine("{0:0.000000}", next);
```

You should really work out which type is most appropriate to you. As a rule of thumb, "artificial" values - especially currency - are most appropriately represented as `decimal`. "Natural" values - such as distances, weights etc - are most appropriately represented as `double`.

Comment: "decimal does retain trailing zeroes" => are you sure about that?

Comment: @Jon: Absolutely. It didn't in .NET 1.0, but it started doing so in .NET 1.1.

Comment: Hmmm... on ideone I got [this](http://ideone.com/z7xFqz). On LINQPad I got `0,75855`. The culture used is obviously different, but it doesn't look like this behavior is standard.

Comment: @Jon: Yes, I get the same result. I know that decimal *does* retain trailing zeroes though - investigating.

Comment: Printing decimal literals retains the zeroes on both platforms. Interesting.

Comment: @Jon: See my edit. If you multiply by 0.000001m instead of dividing by 1000000, it gets the right result. Weird.

Answer (score 2):

Because there is no difference in `0.758550` and `0.75855`, the last `0` is insignificant. You an specify format to get last zero.

```
string strForDisplay = next.ToString("0.0000000");
```

The above will give you the last `0`